# Spring application on Google App Engine fails to initiate due to Cloud Datastore misconfiguration

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine

I want to use a Google Cloud Datastore in my Spring application. I have followed the instructions from [this tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-spring-datastore#0).

I have the following repository:

```
public interface LevelRepository extends DatastoreRepository<Level, Long> {
    ...
}
```

With the following in a controller:

```
@Controller
public class LevelController {
    @Autowired
    LevelRepository levelRepository;
    ...
}
```

And the following in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-data-datastore</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.8.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

The problem is that the application fails at init with the following:

```
Field levelRepository in com.xxx.yyy.LevelController required a bean of type 'com.xxx.yyy.LevelRepository' that could not be found.
The injection point has the following annotations:
@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
Action:
Consider defining a bean of type 'com.xxx.yyy.LevelRepository' in your configuration.
```